# How to fetch the value from an API based on select box value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an API to get the value for dropdown and scoring value.

[image: API screenshot]

1) I have an UI which looks like below screenshot.

[image: UI screenshot]

2) Code is mentioned below:

```
<td>
    <div class="">
        <select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null" id="answer{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" ng-init="question.MasterData;" class="form-control" style="width: 300px; white-space:pre-wrap;">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option ng-repeat="answer in answerData[question.MasterDataCategoryId]" value="{{answer.MasterData}}">{{answer.MasterData}}</option>
        </select>
        <input ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId == null" id="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="question.MasterData" type="text" style="width: 300px;" name="question.QuestionId" class="form-control">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="">
        <span ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId != null">{{question.Score}}</span>
        <select ng-if="question.MasterDataCategoryId == null" id="projectlist" class="form-control" required ng-model="scoring">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option ng-repeat="score in scoringDetails" value="{{score.Score}}">
                {{score.Score}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

Based on the dropdown value I need to dynamically show the scoring which I will get in the same API.

Can any let me know how to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change = "someFunction()"` on your desired dropdown & call your API in that function using `http GET` or `POST` method as following -

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
        // set your scoring variable here
        $scope.scoring = yourValue;    // your value from response
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In ng-change of dropdown write a fucntion which changes the score dropdown value. Suppose the follwing code

In HTML

```
<select ng-change="scoreChange()"  ng-model="dropvalue">
  <option></option>.....
</select>

<select ng-model="score">
  <option></option>.....
</select>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.scoreChange = function(){
  $scope.score = desiredvalue; 
  //or you can call api and assign it here.
}
```